# Is FileInputStream Really Unbuffered?

Tags: java, io

`FileInputStream` uses [this](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/jdk/file/b1fec09a9588/src/share/native/java/io/io_util.c#l74) native method to read bytes in a user supplied buffer. As we can see in the implementation, a user-space buffer is indeed allocated with length `max(BUF_SIZE, supplied buffer length)`. This buffer is then passed to `IO_Read`. I could not pull up the implementation of this method but I am pretty sure this is the standard C buffered reading. Why is `FileInputStream` then said to be unbuffered? And what additional buffering is `BufferedReader` using?

Edit: [Benchmark](https://gist.github.com/suddendust/ba124416af404afea56d5ff3a830aad5) comparing read times of a 100M file and its results:

```
Benchmark                         Mode  Cnt      Score      Error  Units
StreamIOBenchmark.bisMultiBytes   avgt   30     27.640 ±    1.117  ms/op
StreamIOBenchmark.bisSingleBytes  avgt   30    400.552 ±   26.921  ms/op
StreamIOBenchmark.fisMultiBytes   avgt   30     25.231 ±    1.459  ms/op
StreamIOBenchmark.fisSingleBytes  avgt   30  97991.213 ± 5620.685  ms/op
```

The real difference is while reading single bytes, as FIS will be making a new system call for each byte. Hoewver, When reading 8k bytes at once, both FIS (`fisMultiBytes`) and BIS (`bisMultiBytes`) perform pretty similarly.

Comment: The [documentation of `FileInputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/io/FileInputStream.html) makes no guarantee wrt. being buffered/unbuffered.

Comment: The problem with unbuffered IO (like the one in `FileInputStream`) does not show up when you use `read(byte[])` because this usually tries to read as much into the buffer as is possible in one call to the OS. The problem shows up when you repeatedly call [`read()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/io/FileInputStream.html#read()) to read a single byte which calls [`readSingle()`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/jdk/file/b1fec09a9588/src/share/native/java/io/io_util.c#l39)

Comment: @ThomasKläger - It depends on how big your `byte[]` is.

Comment: @ThomasKläger I wrote a benchmark comparing them, can you have a look please? The difference in reading single bytes is huge. However, not so much when reading many bytes at once, because as you said, it'll try to fill in the buffer in one call to the OS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is `FileInputStream` really unbuffered?

Yes.  Really.

> I could not pull up the implementation of this method but I am pretty sure this is the standard C buffered reading.

No it isn't.  The native code is NOT using C buffered I/O.  It is performing a `read(2)` call into a temporary buffer.  Then it copies the data from the temporary buffer to the caller supplied `byte[]`.

In the Java 11u code I am looking at, the temporary buffer is either a small on-stack buffer or a larger native heap buffer that is `malloc`'d and `free`'d during the `native` call.

The relative pathname in the OpenJDK Java 11u codebase is `./src/java.base/share/native/libjava/io_util.c`.  Look for the `readBytes` method.  (This is called via a native entry point method in `./src/java.base/share/native/libjava/FileInputStream.c`)

The `IO_Read` in `io_utils.c` is a macro that aliases `handleRead` which wraps the `read(2)` call.

**UPDATE**

I just noticed that you had already found a link to the Java 8u version of `io_util.c`.  It behaves the same way as the 11u code that I described above.  So maybe you just misread the C code you found?

---

> Why is `FileInputStream` then said to be unbuffered?

It is "said to be" unbuffered because **it really is unbuffered**.

> And what additional buffering is `BufferedReader` using?

You can see that by looking at the (Java) source code for `BufferedReader`.

---

Hint: rather than making (incorrect) assumptions about how the JVM native code implementation works, download and read the OpenJDK source code.  It is available for anyone with enough disk space (1.2GB) to download.

Comment: Thanks for the response. The readBytes method actually uses a user-space buffer to read n bytes, so the difference only arises when we're trying to read 1 byte. However, if I read n bytes into a byte array, both FIS and BIS behave similarly. I actually wrote a benchmark comparing them, and the result corroborate my speculation. I have added the benchmark and its results in an edit to the question. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Yes ... your comment is more or less correct.   The performance of `FileInputStream` and `BufferedInputStream` are close to the same when you do large reads.  However, that is NOT what you asked in the question.  You asked if `FileInputStream` is unbuffered ... and it really is.